# Xamarin: How to go to bottom of ListView using MVVM pattern?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, mvvm, scrollto

Is there a way to go to the bottom of ListView using the MVVM pattern?
I do that using codebehind, but I'd like to do it using MVVM, if possible.

I use the `ScrollTo()` method of ListView.

Thanks

Comment: You can't/shouldn't call View methods directly from within a ViewModel, that wouldn't be MVVM compliant. You could, however, create a Command in your ViewModel and in your Command call a delegate method that you set inside your View's code behind. Then you can bind a Button or other control to that Command. Can you provide some code and also explain why you want to do this? By the way: MVVM is a pattern. Terminology matters ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to attach a delegate method to your ViewModel and invoke the delegate. Another approach would be to use an event handler. You can also subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event if you use an `ObservableCollection`. With either approach you're not breaking the MVVM pattern, because you're applying inversion of control.

*Note that in MVVM the ViewModel must not know anything about Views, therefore it also cannot know that the `ScrollTo()` method even exists. That said, you won't get around calling the `ScrollTo()` method from within your View's code-behind.*

### Solution using delegate

#### ViewModel

In your ViewModel, add and call a delegate like so:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    // delegate
    public delegate void SomethingHappenedDelegate(string item);
    public SomethingHappenedDelegate SomethingHappened = null;

    private ICommand _someCommand;
    public ICommand SomeCommand => _someCommand ??= new Command(SomeMethod);

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var newItem = "hello";
        ListItems?.Add(newItem);
        SomethingHappened?.Invoke(newItem);
    }

    // skipping other stuff like initialization, INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, etc.
}
```

#### View

Then, in your View's code behind, you can set the delegate:

```cs
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel.SomethingHappened = ScrollToBottom;
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void ScrollToBottom(string item)
    {
        MyListView.ScrollTo(item, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
    }
}
```

In your View's XAML, you bind to the command:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Button
      Text="Add item and scroll"
      Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />

    <ListView
      x:Name="MyListView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" />
</StackLayout>
```

You could just as well implement your own event and subscribe to that or use the built-in events of the `ObservableCollection`. That's up to you, but the underlying concept would be the same. You cannot get around having the call to `ScrollTo()` live somewhere in your View`s code behind without breaking MVVM.